# What's the meaning of "\x38\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" in openvpn connection using netcat?

Tags: security, openvpn

I am testing my openvpn server by netcat, 
and I found this answer:
[How to check that an OpenVPN server is listening on a remote port without using OpenVPN client?](https://serverfault.com/questions/262474/how-to-check-that-an-openvpn-server-is-listening-on-a-remote-port-without-using)

by send a magic string "\x38\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
It works well but I am wonder that's the meaning of this string?

Comment: Very old question, but simple. It's magic. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string | File magic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a part of the OpenVPN protocol, indicating some initialisation instructions.  For the exact decoded meaning, you'll probably have to check the OpenVPN source to see exactly what it's saying.

Comment: I downloaded the openvpn source but unfortunately i couldn't find this part, please, what's file? why "\x38\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" exactly? and how did you know or figure out that openvpn is always sending this specific packet, have you used a track method for protocols, packet capture or something else? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but still comes up as the top answer on a Google search for the magical string. I too found the magic string annoying so after some digging through the openvpn source code you can see that 0x38 is op code `P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2` (see [first byte description](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/0f904615bd2eac9d246055ff1ca4e4da95586f86/src/openvpn/ssl_pkt.h#L37-L39) and [opcode value](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/0f904615bd2eac9d246055ff1ca4e4da95586f86/src/openvpn/ssl_pkt.h#L51) in openvpn repo)

The remaining 8 bytes of the packet are just the session ID which for real connections looks to be a random number, but in the example string is a hardcoded 0x0100000000000000 and it results in logs in openvpn server like the following:
`TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]:x.y.z.zz:53832, sid=01000000 00000000`

You can see similar packets are used in [openvpn unit tests](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/0f904615bd2eac9d246055ff1ca4e4da95586f86/tests/unit_tests/openvpn/test_pkt.c#L98-L100):