# How can I test connectivity to a TLS-enabled OpenVPN server?

Tags: monitoring, openvpn, tls

Unfortunately we don't have access to the management interface, so I'm after a way to tell that tls-enabled OpenVPN us up and responsive. I'm familiar with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/262474/how-to-check-that-an-openvpn-server-is-listening-on-a-remote-port-without-using) trick, but it doesn't work for tls-enabled OpenVPN. Currently the only option I can think of is to have a client connect to it with no pull and check stdout for success.